# VLC doesn't start from command line

Tags: command-line, 20.04, vlc

When trying to launch VLC from command line it only reports back its version number and quits:

```
~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
~$
```

Launching it via 'Activities' search works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: One question per question. You have 2 questions here and no info to help you with either.

Comment: Just meant upgrading to newer version and see if it works then is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, I just re-install the `vlc` package from apt and it works again:

```sh
sudo apt install vlc
```